# $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\operatorname dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$ by Variable Substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I am reviewing some calculus and am trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$$

The problem states that it can be evaluated by switching to $\theta$ defined by $x=a\sin\theta$. I have made a little progress on solving it but I am getting stuck. Could someone walk me through the evaluation of this integal?

Comment: Have you used $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by $x1$ and $x2$?  Do you mean $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: @Théophile Yes, so by doing that I get $\int \frac{dx}{a\cos\theta}$, and I think I can use $dx/d\theta = -a\sin\theta$, but at that point I'm stuck

Comment: @AndrewChin, yes I meant $x_1$ and $x_2$, just the limits of the integral.

Comment: The derivative of $\sin \theta$ is $\cos \theta$, so you should have $dx = a\cos\theta d\theta$. Then you're just a step away.

Comment: Oops, not sure why I said $dx/d\theta=-a\sin\theta$ I meant $a\cos\theta$.

Comment: You might find this process easier to see if you substitute the $x$ and $dx$ at the same time. It can get confusing if you have an integral that's in terms of both $x$ and $d\theta$.

Comment: So then I get $\int \frac{a\cos\theta d\theta}{ a\cos\theta} = \theta$. And so solving for $\theta = sin^{-1}(x/a)$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Now put in the limits $x_1$ and $x_2$ to complete the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = \dfrac xa\implies \mathrm dx = a\,\mathrm du$. Therefore, $$\begin{align}\int\dfrac1{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}\,\mathrm dx&\equiv\int\dfrac a{\sqrt{a^2 - a^2u^2}}\,\mathrm du \\ &= \int\dfrac1{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}\,\mathrm du\tag{1}\end{align}$$

Notice that $(1)$ is a [standard integral](http://www.math.com/tables/integrals/tableof.htm) of $\arcsin(u)$. So, $$\int\dfrac1{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}\,\mathrm du = \arcsin(u)\equiv\arcsin\left(\dfrac xa\right) + C.$$

In fact, we know that the [standard integral](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MTH_211_Calculus_II/Chapter_5%3A_Integration/5.7%3A_Integrals_Resulting_in_Inverse_Trigonometric_Functions_and_Related_Integration_Techniques) for $\displaystyle\int\dfrac1{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}\,\mathrm dx$ is $\arcsin\left(\dfrac xa\right) + C$, and so you didn't really even have to substitute $u = \dfrac xa$ in the first place.